# Button in li element to display more details

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, spfx

I would like to display the modal window with more details when I click on record. I'm using OfficeUI.

My parent component:

```
public render() {
    {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items
                    .map((item: IListItem, i: number): JSX.Element => <ul className="list-group">
                        <li className="list-group-item">
                            <div className={styles.text}>
                                <p>{item.Id}</p>
                            </div>
                            <DefaultButton onClick={this.showModalEvent} text="Open Modal" />
                            {this.state.showPopup
                                ? <ModalPopUpItem item={item} 
                                        showModalState={this.state.showPopup}
                                        showModal={this.showModalEvent}/> : null
                            }
                        </li>
                    </ul>)}
            </div>
        );
    }



    private showModalEvent = (): void => {
    this.setState({ showPopup: !this.state.showPopup });
}
```

My child:

```
export class ModalPopUpItem extends React.Component<IModalProps> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                isOpen={this.props.showModalState}
                onDismiss={this.props.showModal}
                isBlocking={false}
                containerClassName="ms-modalExample-container">
                <div className="ms-modalExample-header">
                    <span>{this.props.item.date}</span>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click my **DeafultButton** on parent component it invokes and displays **Modal** for every item, how can I limit this to only one current clicked item. I tried with **i: number**, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using single state for every child, so once you change `this.state.showPopup` to true, every modal will showed up. So you might can change the `showModalEvent` method.

```
private showModalEvent = (id: number): void => {
    this.setState({ showPopupId: id });
```

and the render will be look like

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.items
      .map((item: IListItem, i: number): JSX.Element => <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item">
          <div className={styles.text}>
            <p>{item.Id}</p>
          </div>
          <DefaultButton onClick={() => this.showModalEvent(item.Id)} text="Open Modal" />
          {this.state.showPopupId === item.Id
            ? <ModalPopUpItem item={item}
              showModalState={this.state.showPopup}
              showModal={this.showModalEvent} /> : null
          }
        </li>
      </ul>)}
  </div>
);
```

Since this method only store one id at a time, this mean only one modal will showed up. If you want to show more modal at the time, you could change it to array or something.

Comment: Thanks coool, I figure it out with your explanation. I tried to resolve this in other way.

Comment: Great! Glad it help :D

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component only has one flag to store the `showPopup`. This means that when you click on one of your buttons you set this flag for the whole parent component and that means that the whole list of your child components is evaluated and `this.state.showPopup` will be true.

You need to find a way to limit the effect of clicking the button to the item the button was clicked on.

You could, for example, not set the `showPopup` flag on the parent component, but on the `item`.

This could work, but you would have to revisit the way you include the `ModalPopUpItem`.

```
private showModalEvent = (item): void => {
    item.showPopup = !item.showPopup;
}
```